# Redirect automatically all links from one basic-URL to another?

Tags: javascript, php, apache, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have the following problem: We have a website that has multiple hrefs for images - They all use the same domain. Which is something like:

```
<a href="http://img.example-domain.com">Avatar</a><br/>
```

But the server this domain is using is currently inactive, but it'll come back at some point, I just do not know when.

Now, we have a new image server, that is hosted on AWS.
But since the code has many entries using the old domain, I would like to know how can I redirect ALL requests to that domain to another one, instead of editing the code itself.

For example Each request from "img.example-domain.com", shall be redirected to "img.example-domain.com.amazon.etc"

Please, how can I do this?

I am using Apache and would prefer a solution that involves using Apache Rewrite module or something like that... But if it is not possible, I will be OK too with a code solution.

Thanks in advance, to everyone.

Comment: What control do you have of this domain/hostname? Presumably if the server it is currently pointing to is "inactive" then you need to point this hostname somewhere that is active. In which case, why not point it directly at your "new image server"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may add this to your .htaccess -->

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^img.example-domain.com$ [OR]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.img.example-domain.com$
  RewriteRule (.*)$ http://www.img.example-domain.com.amazon.etc/$1 [R=302,L]
</IfModule>
```

**Please note:** the `[R=302,L]` only applies to "temporary" redirects, for a permanent solution, replace with `[R=301,L]`

Comment: This shouldn't be a "301" (permanent) redirect if the server "will come back at some point".

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly.

Comment: Wait, what? @MrWhite What do you mean by permanent? Should i remove R=301? Isnt just as easy as just commeting this after i get the server running again?

Comment: @RaulChiarella A 301 is considered a "permanent" redirect. This results in user-agents/browsers caching the redirect persistently. If you need to remove this redirect at some point it should be "temporary", ie a 302. Browser's generally do not cache 302 redirects.

Comment: Thank you, i adjusted to 302.

Comment: Adjusted my post. Thanks for catching that @MrWhite.

Answer (score 0):

you need to setup a new server to your domain that's redirects paths to the new one

you can do it with a simple node js server like this

```js
const http = require("http");
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  const path = req.url;
  res.writeHead(302, { "Location": "http://new-domain.com" + path });
  res.end();
});

server.listen(port);
```

**Note**: don't forget to change `http://new-domain.com` to the real new domain

**Edited**

*You can even do it simply by using a free web host like **heroku** with this node js server and linking the host with the old domain*

Comment: Thanks... I found that using mod_rewrite on apache was a bit easier for me.